# Capture mouse movement in win32/Opengl

Tags: c++, c, winapi, opengl

At the moment I simply use the WM_MOUSEMOVE message, but it limits the mouse movement to the maximum resolution. So what's the best way of capturing the mouse with Win32 (on a OpenGl window)? I don't want to use freeglut or any extra library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For games and realtime [DirectInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is very suitable, it's moderately hard to use.

That is not core win32 api, the winapi way of getting the input is either [GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[SetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) driven by your own update loop, so you query and reset with your own frequency.

Or [SetCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then upon [WM_MOUSEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you call [SetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
The point of setting the cursor pos is to give room for movement so you can get the delta, the amount the cursor moved since the last update and then put it back the cursor into the center of your window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to capture mouse events after the mouse has existed the window, then you might want to look into the [SetCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

If your problem is that you want to make a FPS game and you want your character to be able to spin in a continuous motion, then you want to set the mouse position to the center of the window after each mouse move event and handle input based on the difference between the position of the cursor when the mouse move event is fired and the center of the screen. To set the position of the mouse you can use the [SetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bets are to either use [DirectInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which can be a bit of a pain to set up) or [RawInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There is a fairly comprehensive example available in the [Using RawInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#example_2) page (See example 2).